# R ggplot2 stat_summary : error when plotting the minimum threshold

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently trying to plot a simple stat_summary(fun.y=mean,fun.ymin=min, fun.ymax=max,geom="pointrange"...

There is no error message, but minimum thresholds plotted are false, supposed to be around 4-5 they are allocated at 0.

The code I use is :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)


p=ggplot(data,aes(x=Date,y=ED))+

   stat_summary(fun.y=mean,fun.ymin=min, fun.ymax=max,geom="pointrange",colour='grey60',width=.5,size=1)+

   # scale axes
   scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(2,10,2))+
   scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m"), breaks='6 months')+

   # theme
   theme(legend.position = "none")+
   theme_bw()+
   theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 16,face='bold'))+
   theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
         axis.text.y=element_text(size=14,face='bold'),
         axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))

p
```

In the dataset, there are 3 values of ED per date, respectively corresponding to mean, minimum and maximum values. Here is the dataset :

```
> data
         Date   ED
1  2000-10-23 6.64
2  2000-10-23 5.28
3  2000-10-23 8.01
4  2001-05-08 5.89
5  2001-05-08 5.05
6  2001-05-08 6.73
7  2001-10-23 7.27
8  2001-10-23 5.55
9  2001-10-23 8.99
10 2002-05-08 5.83
11 2002-05-08 4.92
12 2002-05-08 6.75
13 2002-10-23 7.60
14 2002-10-23 5.67
15 2002-10-23 9.53
16 2003-05-08 5.83
17 2003-05-08 4.92
18 2003-05-08 6.75
19 2003-10-23 7.60
20 2003-10-23 5.67
21 2003-10-23 9.53
22 2004-05-07 5.83
23 2004-05-07 4.92
24 2004-05-07 6.75
25 2004-10-22 7.60
26 2004-10-22 5.67
27 2004-10-22 9.53
28 2005-05-07 5.83
29 2005-05-07 4.92
30 2005-05-07 6.75
31 2005-10-22 7.60
32 2005-10-22 5.67
33 2005-10-22 9.53
```

I have already checked values in the dataset, the format is numeric, there is no 0, negative values neither NA.

```
# check values
class(data$ED)
data$ED[is.na(data$ED)]
data$ED[data$ED<=0]
min(data$ED)
tapply(data$ED,list(data$Date),min)
tapply(data$ED,list(data$Date),max)
```

Since mean and maximum values seem to be correctly plotted, I don't understand what I did wrong in this code.
I'll be glad to read any idea.

Thank you,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the argument `width` in `stat_summary()` is causing the problem. You should remove it. `geom_linerange()` does not allow it anyway (it uses `size` instead).

```
p=ggplot(data,aes(x=Date,y=ED))+

  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,fun.ymin=min, fun.ymax=max,
    geom="pointrange",colour='grey60',size=1)+

  # scale axes
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(2,10,2))+
  ylim(2,10) +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m"), breaks='6 months')+

  # theme
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 16,face='bold'))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=14,face='bold'),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))

p
```

[image]

I have no explanation as to why this error happens. I guess it is passed to another function where it is interpreted in a way that introduces 0 values in the data.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Surprisingly, i previously used this code for another dataset and had no issue. It is like sometimes this argument "width" is taken into account and doesn't disturb anything and sometimes not. Thanks again